# How much time Android Market take to upload saw the upload Application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, google-play

I have Just Upload the Paid aaplication to the Android Market.
But i am not able to seen it right now on android Market. I think android market will first check it and then will put it on the android market.
But i want to know in how much time they will put my application on android market ?
Give your suggestion and answers.
thanks.

Comment: I have a paid app on the Android Market and recent upgrades show that it takes somewhere between 30 and 45 minutes when the app becomes available for downloads or upgrads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fixed time, it may takes either 1 hour or 1 day or more than this.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, it can sometimes take a little bit of time.  This is mainly due to caching and such, but you should be able to directly hit your application by hitting the fully qualified URL:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.your.package.name

Answer (score 1):

From experience, it might take up to a day for your app (or app updates for that matter) to show up in the market. But it will happen, no worries! Google doesn't do any sort of approval process, they just put up whatever you upload, so I'm not sure what causes the delay.