# How much time google take to validate app...?

Tags: android

i have uploaded an app yesterday by 6pm but till now i can't find app on Google Play..
Can anyone find an app otherthan private inbox on think link..
please help..

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=AMTEC+Pvt.Ltd
Does anyone know how much time it will take to upload an app..?
Does time to become visible has anything to do with the content of app..??
I have already uploaded one app that took about few hours but now its almost 24 hours...

Comment: I assume you have published it?

Comment: i can see app in given link on google play

Comment: @Richa can you see an app named Tricky Taka Demo..??

Comment: @ Ian yes i have published it.. but still i cant find it on Google Play..

Comment: I can't see your new app, I thought there was no validation process, maybe if you unpublish and republish it might show up.

Comment: @Ian I think i saw on some website that from 2012 February onwards Goole Play have some validation to find if apps contain malware trojans etc..

Comment: Private Inbox is the name of app.which is there in the link given by u

Comment: yes thats link of account with list of all apps. i just red that there might be some filters so you may not be able to see apps... i was wondering if it was due to some filtering i cant see my new app...

Comment: @ Richa thanks for your effort..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much time Android Market take to upload saw the upload Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500260/how-much-time-android-market-take-to-upload-saw-the-upload-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no validation process after a successful publishing of your app on the Play Store.

Few points to consider:

- It will take some time to appear in search results.
- If you are using the Google Play Store application on your Android device, then keep in mind that the application could get filtered out due to various criteria and not be visible in the search results of the application, even if it is published. It could be filtered out based on country, screen sizes/resolutions, minimum SDK versions, phone capabilities and much more.

Check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/filters.html) about `Filters on Google Play` to see how some choices in `AndroidManifest.xml` could also be affecting your application from appearing in Search via the Play Store app on different Android devices.

Comment: i did verify those aganist my manifest file but i use only permission and uses sdk filter nothing else....

Comment: By any chance, are you checking on a phone where the Android version is lower than the minimum SDK specified in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: version is based on 2.3.3 am checking from my phone 2.3.6 both require an sdk of level 10

Comment: Can you tell me if you are able to see the app via the web site : https://play.google.com/store and if yes, can you try to directly send the app to the device and see if it is able to do so ?

Comment: OK. Then I suggest that you a) Wait for some more time to see if it appears in the Play website from your desktop. b) If yes, first try to send it directly to your phone from the website on the desktop c) If no, then try republishing it.

Comment: okay do i need to change package name..? or can i publish the same existing apk ? do i need to make a new key for this...??

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times, this happens. The app may be uploaded on the play store but may not be  displayed immediately in the search results. You can check whether the app is uploaded or not by going to this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yourpackagename
Replace 'yourpackagename' with the package name.
If the app is displayed, your upload was successful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i tried this too but still i cant find my app

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amtec.TrickyTracky.Demo this is the link that i am looking for

Comment: You should unpublish and then republish the app. I had faced a similar problem with one of my apps and doing this fixed the problem.

Comment: okay i think i should wait for tomorrow if cant find app then will  republish it.. can we use the same package name while republishing...? do we need to make any changes on our app...??

Comment: You can use the same package name.

Comment: same package name will do and no modification is needed.